# Migrating Workflow WSP to Group Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow

I am trying to move a workflow from a classic site to a modern group site.

I saved the old wf as a template.  However, uploading the wsp to the site collection's (domainname.sharepoint.com) Solutions library does not work as I guess group sites (domainname.sharepoint.com/sites/mygroupsite) are not part of that site collection and therefore when I go to Site Settings> Manage Site Features, the workflow is not showing up so I can't activate it.

How do I enable this 2010 reusable workflow on the new group site?  Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you activate the workflow in Solution Gallery?

[image]

Please refer below article to Migrate Reusable SharePoint Online Designer Workflows From One Site Collection To Another:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40277.migrate-reusable-sharepoint-online-designer-workflows-from-one-site-collection-to-another.aspx